# Polymer Paper Elements in ASP.NET MVC via Nuget?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, polymer, material-design, polymer-1.0

With the recent release of Polymer 1.0 I was hoping to use the Paper Elements in a ASP.NET MVC/Microsoft Stack, or at least check them out.

I have used nuget in the Visual Studio package manager to attempt to install polymer:

```
    PM> Install-Package polymer
    Installing 'polymer 1.0.0'.
    Successfully installed 'polymer 1.0.0'.
    Adding 'polymer 1.0.0' to Eqs.Mvc.Web.
    Successfully added 'polymer 1.0.0' to Eqs.Mvc.Web.

    PM> Install-Package paper-elements
    ...long long list of dependency imports
```

When I try to import paper-elements.html I notice that in paper-elements.html there are missing files and files in the wrong locations.
For example in paper-elements.html:

`<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">`

is actually located in the project at the scripts root:

`<link rel="import" href="../polymer.html">`

I get a lot of 404 errors.  Did I import the packages incorrectly?

Comment: tl;dr  I installed polymer 1.0 and paper-elements 1.0 using nuget in VS; references from paper-elements to polymer are wrong. Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively my company, FrostAura Consolidated now manages a package that you might find useful. This package scaffolds all core and paper components with a demo of how to create a custom web component with automated documentation and unit testing. Check it out at https://www.nuget.org/packages/FrostAura.Dynamics.Polymer.Kickstart/

Comment: This worked.  Now I have to try to figure out how to bind elements such as paper-input to my model...

Comment: The answer to my how to bind question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815159/how-do-you-bind-polymer-elements-to-a-model-in-asp-net/34818257#34818257

Answer (score 10):

Don't use *NuGet* to get polymer elements (as it's not maintained by Google so it's not up-to-date), use [Bower](http://bower.io/) instead.

### Prior to ASP.NET 5

1. Go to *NuGet*'s *Package Management Console* and install [Bower](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bower/).

   > PM> Install-Package Bower
2. Navigate to your **web project folder** in *File Explorer* and then **Shift + Right Click** anywhere to select *Open command window here* in the context menu.
3. Inside the command prompt, run the following commands one after another.

   > bower init
   >
   > bower install --save Polymer/polymer
   >
   > bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-elements
4. Whenever there's a new version, run the following command.

   > bower update.

### ASP.NET 5

It's a lot simpler in ASP.NET 5, since the project already adds a *bower.json* file for you. So you just need to add the dependencies there -

```
{
  "name": "Portal",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "^1.1.3",
    "paper-elements": "PolymerElements/paper-elements#^1.0.3",
    ...
}
```

Once all dependencies are added, go to your Visual Studio web project and enable *Show All Files*. You will see a folder called `bower_components`, just include it into your project.

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521889/how-to-use-bower-installed-from-nuget-in-visual-studio/26521928#26521928) I asked too.

Comment: I installed Bower and did the init and install commands.  I see paper-element directories but no files.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: What's the output when you do bower install --save polymerelements/paper-elements? Maybe try running cmd prompt using admin privileges?

Comment: That helped a lot!!  after running cmd in admin mode
I ran
   bower cache clean
   bower update
and I seem to have downloaded all of the files, however they are in a weird place under my project in:
   .bin\public\lib\polymer
I am guessing that my bower.json settings are not pointing to my project directory.  That should not be too hard to find.

Comment: You know what, don't use the path from the package management console, use the path of your web project. And then do the commands from there.

Comment: Just updated the answer. So try using the path of your web project folder and it should download the files to the right folder!

Answer (score 0):

you may need run Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted in windows powershell to allow Bower install scripts to run...